# reCAPTCHA v3 not working angular 6 - error executing

Tags: angular, google-api, recaptcha, captcha, recaptcha-v3

I am implementing Google reCAPTCHA v3 with Angular 6.

```
<script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?render=KEY'></script>
```

Added script in `index.html`

In my AppComponent,

```
constructor(
    @Inject(DOCUMENT) private document: any
) {
    this.grecaptcha = this.document.grecaptcha;
}
```

and when i click form submit,

```
this.grecaptcha.execute('KEY', { action: 'action_name' })
  .then(function (token) {
      // Verify the token on the server.
      console.log(token);
});
```

But,

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'execute' of undefined

Answer (score 1):

the object should be available from window, so all you need is to declare it on top of your ts file:

```
declare const grecaptcha: any;
```

then you can use it in your class like:

```
grecaptcha.execute('KEY', { action: 'action_name' })
  .then(function (token) {
      // Verify the token on the server.
      console.log(token);
})
```

You can also try to install the typings `@types/grecaptcha`, to get some type hinting to make your life a bit easier

Comment: `Property 'grecaptcha' does not exist on type 'Window'`

Comment: still it's not getting `grecaptcha`

Answer (score 1):

- First, make sure that you are adding the right script and siteKey of V3 reCaptcha in `index.html` (not V2)... The right script and siteKey will help you to load external google library and make it available in `window.grecaptcha`.
  I suggest you another way to add script by typescript code in your `component.ts`. Just call this function in `onInit()` or `AfterViewInit()`.

```
addScriptSrc() {
  let script: any = document.getElementById('script');
  if (!script) {
    script = document.createElement('script');
  }
  const body = document.body;
  script.innerHTML = '';
  script.src = 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?render=<your_sitekey>';
  script.async = false;
  script.defer = true;
  body.appendChild(script);
 }
```

- Second, after adding script and sitekey, in your `component.ts`, just need to declare the window object by
  `declare const window: any;`
- Finally, when your form submit:

```
window.grecaptcha.ready(function() {
        window.grecaptcha.execute(<sitekey>, {action: 'signup'}).then((token) => {
             //Do anything with captcha token
        });
    });
```

`ready()` function make sure that the external library is successfully loaded from google api, before you `execute` it to get token.