# Angular recaptcha v3, code is showing error, not able to execute the function

Tags: angular, recaptcha

I am using recaptcha v3 with Angular and facing executing error.

```
click(){
  this.grecaptcha.execute();
  this.grecaptcha.ready('6LfwjpEUAAAAAHTtLNdC42zZZ64LM8nPqXf47vuZ', { action: 'stackblitz' })
  .then(function (token) {
      // Verify the token on the server.
      console.log(token);
  });
}
```

please check console of my stackblitz link

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-captcha1?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

I used below stack question but it didn't help me out

[reCAPTCHA v3 not working angular 6 - error executing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53761994/recaptcha-v3-not-working-angular-6-error-executing).

---

**UPDATE:**

I am getting the error, ERROR
Error: Cannot read property 'execute' of undefined.

in HTML I tried

```
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?render=6LfwjpEUAAAAAHTtLNdC42zZZ64LM8nPqXf47vuZ"></script>
```

in ts , on submit I am calling

```
declare const grecaptcha: any;
onsubmit(){
    this.grecaptcha.ready(() => {
     {
        this.grecaptcha.execute('6LfwjpEUAAAAAHTtLNdC42zZZ64LM8nPqXf47vuZ', {action: 'information'}).then(function(token) {
           console.log(token);
        });
     }
```

})
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First note, you should post your code, since links tend to die. Secondly, when checking the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/v3), it states that this is how it is called:

```ts
<script>
  grecaptcha.ready(function() {
    grecaptcha.execute('site_key', {action: 'homepage'}).then(function(token) {
       // ...
    });
  });
</script>
```

So you should first call `grecaptcha.ready`, before `execute`, so, like in the question you linked, declare `grecaptcha` outside the component and call the function in your component:

```ts
declare const grecaptcha: any;

// ...

grecaptcha.ready(() => {
  grecaptcha.execute('sitekey', { action: 'test' }).then((token) => {
    console.log(token);
  });
});
```

Also when looking at the grecaptcha, seems you are using some kind of test key, in v 3 you need to create your own key and add the domain in contrary with v 2 where you could try a test key provided by google.

If you are developing on localhost, add `http://127.0.0.1/` as domain when you register to get your keys. Because of this restriction, I cannot "fix" the stackblitz you provided.

I tried the above code in a test project, and it worked wonderfully for me :)

Comment: I tried this code too, it not even showing badge to me

Comment: I don't know what to say, this code works perfectly for me. Did you create your own keys?`

Comment: Yes, i created my own keys  and the error is ..........................Cannot read property 'execute' of undefined
    at Object.eval [as handleEvent] (InformationComponent.html:47)
    at handleEvent (core.js:21673)
    at callWithDebugContext (core.js:22767)
    at Object.debugHandleEvent [as handleEvent] (core.js:22470)
    at dispatchEvent (core.js:19122)
    at core.js:19569
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (platform-browser.js:993)
    at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:421)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:16147)

Comment: I created at top of the ts file for same component, if its not right, where I should declare it

Comment: I see now that you are using `this`. Please re-read my code, you are not doing it right. And by the way, if you edit your question, don't modify the original, add just an update of what you tried next ;)

Comment: sorry for that, I did it to explain about current sitution

Comment: now it says ............RROR ReferenceError: grecaptcha is not defined
    at InformationComponent.push../src/app/features/demographic/components/information/information.component.ts.InformationComponent.next (information.component.ts:29)
    at Object.eval [as handleEvent] (InformationComponent.html:47)

Comment: I don't know what you are doing :D This is how your code should look like: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-captcha1-ixqjul?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: for information html, I used that <script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?render=6LfwjpEUAAAAAHTtLNdC42zZZ64LM8nPqXf47vuZ"></script>..................................
for information.ts I used
declare const grecaptcha: any;

////

 next() {
  this.router.navigate(['/demographic/person']);

grecaptcha.ready(() => {
 {
 grecaptcha.execute('6LfwjpEUAAAAAHTtLNdC42zZZ64LM8nPqXf47vuZ', {action: 'person'}).then(function(token) {
    console.log(token);
 });
 }
})}

Comment: Please modify the stackblitz to what your code looks like now, with the example stackblitz you gave.

Comment: thanks worked for me. but its showing captcha badge on all the pages, the error was i was using <script> for component html instead of index html

Comment: Okay, cool that it got sorted out! Please consider marking the question as solved if it helped you :) As for the captcha badge showing everywhere, I think that is a separate question. At least I don't have time to dig into that now. I actually haven't used v3 even before, so I can't help you with that now on the fly. Somebody else probably knows this a lot better than I do!